# Java Arrays[] - Assigning Specific Elements in a For Loop to Certain Values

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I was attempting to write some code for a program in BlueJ (Java) that lists bags and adds and removes items from those bags, that sort of thing. Then I got stuck in the first class; I couldn't get to add an item to the bag properly as you can notice below in the addItem() method; it keeps adding String s to every null element in the array rather the first encountered. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Best wishes & many thanks,

Xenos

```
public class Bag1 {
    private String[] store; // This is an array holding mutlitple strings.

    public Bag1(int storageCapacity) {
        store = new String[storageCapacity];
    } // That was the primitive array constructor.

    public boolean isFull() {
        boolean full = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
            if(store[i] == null) {
                full = false;
            }
        }
        return full;
    } // The method above checks if the bag is full or not, and returns a boolean value on that basis.

    public void add(String s) {
        for(int i = store.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(store[i] == null) {
                store[i] = s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing is to start laying out your code in a rather more conventional fashion - don't put lots of statements on one line, put the closing brace on a separate line, etc. Your code will be *much* easier to read that way...

Comment: Have you learnt `break;` or `return;`, because that's what you need here. Or a boolean variable indicating that you have added something and that the loop should stop. Please learn to indent your code, for your own understanding of your own code. Also indices in an array go from 0 to length - 1. So this code should thro an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should exit the loop after finding the first empty spot :

```
public void add(String s) 
{
    for(int i=store.length-1; i>=0; i--) { // note the change in the starting index
        if(store[i]==null) {
            store[i] = s;
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```